# How prevent header being injected with malicious redirects [1.9.3.3]?

Tags: magento-1.9.3.3

My Magento 1.9.3.3 installation had malicious redirects injected into the header. I could easily erase the redirects from **System/Configuration/Design/HTML Header/Other Header Content** field.

However I would like to know how to prevent it from happening again.

I am not well-versed when it comes to locking down Magento, but I took the following steps:

1. Via SSH I ran

   - `find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`
   - `find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;`
   - `chmod 550 mage` to make sure permissions were set correctly.
2. I changed the admin password.

I did find that the admins user group had 20+ accounts I had never created. I erased those.

Are there additional steps I should/could take at this point?

Comment: Check your site with Magereport.com, do you have any missing patches ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: After removing the fake admin accounts and changing admin path and database password, the issue has not returned.

Comment: Sounds good ... is changing admin path too worth an accepted answer? ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it's same problem as descriebed here:

- [Magento website redirect to "https://ribinski.us/redirect_base/redirect.js"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/183081/magento-website-redirect-to-https-ribinski-us-redirect-base-redirect-js/183088#183088)
- [Website start redirecting to another url](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182920/website-start-redirecting-to-another-url)

I don't know how they got access, so first things (as posted in related questions) could be

- changing DB password *(and all others too)*
- maybe change admin path
- apply all patches *(just to mention ... you're already up2date)*
- check admin accounts *(as you did)*
- check server for malicious scripts

<sup>Wait for possible fix ... :(</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. I've applied them all and asked my host to scan for known infections. Also thanks for editing the formatting of my post, I should've paid more attention.

I wonder if finally upgrading to 2.x would make my site more secure or not really...

Comment: As written in another question it seems that only 1.9.x is affected. So updating to 2.x could help. After several users reported this i think its Not related to an extension. I hope changing credentials prevents you from further damage - at least for the next days. (maybe another patch is released - if its related to core code). Btw, formating was okay, just changed for better readablity :)

Comment: These steps were very helpful in resolving the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how these attacks are happening but you could change the frontName in local.xml

```
<admin>
 <routers>
  <adminhtml>
    <args>
      <frontName><![CDATA[something_not_easily_guessed]]></frontName>
    </args>
  </adminhtml>
 </routers>
</admin>
```